# Best way to implement screens switching back and forth

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-widget

I have a list - in this list is contacts which each (when clicked) will have a screen so the user can chat to that contact.

When the user comes out of that screen to go back to the list (and maybe click on another contact screen) but then goes back to the first chat screen I want the user to see the same content as before (messages).

what is the way to implement this? I cant seem to find a definitive answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're targeting newer versions of android, then Fragments may be the way to go.  If you want the app to work on older versions, then I'd go for `ViewSwitcher`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your chat messages in an SQLite database and load them when you open your Activity.

Comment: I was thinking this (store and re add to screen) might be the way to go, thanks Benito and Aleks G.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Activity which shows your chat messages, and another activity which shows Contacts,
By using this model you can retain old contents of that activiy too.